# How to generate a function with a name pre-determined by an algorithm through a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Let's say I need to input an X number of strings. The letters of each string must be separated in a variable that has the name that follows the following pattern: `(PositionOfTheCharacterInTheString)+String+(OrdinaryPositionOfTheString)`.

For example, we have strings:

- 1="ABC"
- string 2="XYZ"
- string Y="HIJ"

I need that a function when called create the following variables:

```
1String1="A"
2String1="B"
3String1="C"
1String2="X"
2String2="Y"
3String2="Z"
1String3="H"
2String3="I"
3String3="J"
```

How would I go about doing it?

I also would like to know how to generate through a function variables with names like "1","2","3"... and "A","B", "C", "D"...

Thanks.

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually format your post* so that only *code* goes in code blocks, and show what you've tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: Note you cant create variables that start with a number, if you need a container for your data and require that naming scheme you will need to use an object with those names as keys, eg `{"1String1":"A",...}`

Comment: CertainPerformance, it is the fault of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to do this. JavaScript does not support variable variables. Maybe you want to do is something like:

```js
function Organizer(){
  const a = [];
  for(let i=0,s,l=arguments.length; i<l; i++){
    a.push([]);
  }
  a.forEach((v, i)=>{
    s = arguments[i].split('');
    s.forEach((r, q)=>{
      a[q].push(r);
    });
  });
  this.getArray = ()=>{
    return a;
  }
  this.getWeird = fakeVar=>{
    const s = fakeVar.split(/string/i);
    return a[s[0]-1][s[1]-1];
  }
}
const org = new Organizer('ABC', 'XYZ', 'HIJ');
console.log(org.getWeird('3String2'));
console.log(org.getWeird('2String3'));
```

Of course, I would just use Array access, instead.